# Select all rows from the previous date

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting

I am trying to make a SQL query (to be converted into a SSRS report) that will grab everything opened in the previous day.  This will have to be ran every day, automatically, so entering in the date manually will not be an option really.

Comment: Look at DateAdd() with negative increment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Safest (in terms of changes to, or implicit conversion of, underlying data types) and most efficient (in terms of best chance at using an index to seek) is an open-ended range:

```
WHERE datetime_column >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 1, GETDATE()),0)
  AND datetime_column <  DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()),0);
```

For some details, see:

- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE CAST(DATE_Column AS DATE) = CAST(DATEADD(DAY, - 1, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
```

Comment: While this is the one exception in all of SQL Server where applying an expression against the column in the WHERE clause still yields a sargeable expression, it can still lead to disastrous cardinality estimates ([please see this question on dba.se](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea)). Sometimes what looks like a shortcut isn't always the best solution. A range query is much, much safer.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thank you for pointing this out and the for the link very informative. cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
select DATEADD(DD,-1,getDate()) as Yesterday

select * from <table> where date_in_question = DATEADD(DD,-1,getDate())
```

If you only need the date, do this

```
declare @yesterday as Date

set @yesterday = cast(DATEADD(DD,-1,getDate()) as Date)

select * from <table> where date_in_question = @yesterday
```

Comment: looks like a date and time since he is referring to activity date. You have to CAST your column too.

Comment: He would have to cast the column if it is a date time in the data table, good point, thanks

Comment: Also please don't use lazy shorthand like `DD`. `DAY` is only one extra character and is so much more self-documenting. For some examples of lazy shorthand that is anything but intuitive, [read this post](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx).